# If stack operations are constant time O(1), what is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, theory

BinaryConversion:
We are inputting a positive integer n with the output being a binary representation of n on a stack.

What would the time complexity here be? I'm thinking it's O(n) as the while loop halves every time, meaning the iterations for a set of inputs size 'n' decrease to n/2, n/4, n/8 etc.

Applying sum of geometric series whereby n = a and r = 1/2, we get 2n.

Any help appreciated ! I'm still a noob.

```
create empty stack S
while n > 0 do
    push (n mod 2) onto S
    n = floor(n / 2)
end while
return S
```

Comment: The added answer isn't what you were looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the loop was

```
while n>0:
    for i in range n:
        # some action
    n = n/2
```

Then the complexity would have been `O(n + n/2 + n/4 ... 1)` ~ `O(n)`, and your answer would have been correct.

```
while n > 0 do
    # some action
    n = n / 2
```

Here however, the complexity will should be the number of times the outer loop runs, since the amount of work done in each iteration is `O(1)`. So the answer will be `O(log(n))` (since `n` is getting halved each time).

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations is the number of times you have to divide n by 2 to get 0, which is O(log n).